# Matching records from a single table with filter on same columnn

Tags: mysql

Updates: It seems that solution did not fix the issue so I am trying to explain in a better way.

I am trying to implement a filter on products display, which has many custom fields and values.

E.g.

Color: Red, Blue, Green
Material: Silver, Gold, Platinum
Manufacturer: MF1, MF2, MF3

Now if someone wants to select all products with Color as Red & Blue, Material as Gold and Manufacturer as MF1, what would be the correct SQL. Please see the DB schema at Fiddle at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6373d/2/0

I am using this query as suggested but it is not showing the correct results:

```
SELECT d1.productid, d1.fieldid, d1.value FROM `xcart_extra_field_values` d1 LEFT JOIN xcart_products_categories AS cat ON d1.productid = cat.productid WHERE (d1.fieldid= '36' AND d1.value LIKE '%14 karat guld%') AND cat.categoryid = '797' UNION ALL SELECT d2.productid, d2.fieldid, d2.value FROM `xcart_extra_field_values` d2 LEFT JOIN xcart_products_categories AS cat ON d2.productid = cat.productid WHERE (d2.fieldid= '37' AND d2.value LIKE '%Brillanter%') AND cat.categoryid = '797'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not show what the desired result of your query is but, from what I can tell your query is working but you are only showing the values that are from your table `tbl_fld_val` with the alias `d1`. If you change your query slightly, you will see that the records are present:

```
SELECT d1.productid, d1.fieldid, d1.value
  ,d2.productid d2pid, d2.fieldid d2did, d2.value d2val
FROM tbl_fld_val d1
INNER JOIN tbl_fld_val d2 
  ON d1.productid=d2.productid
WHERE (d1.fieldid= 36 AND d1.value LIKE '%Søl%') 
  AND (d2.fieldid= 37 AND d2.value LIKE '%Farvede%');
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70091/5)

If you want the data in to appear in the same columns, then you can use a `UNION ALL` similar to this:

```
SELECT d1.productid, d1.fieldid, d1.value
FROM tbl_fld_val d1
WHERE (d1.fieldid= 36 AND d1.value LIKE '%Søl%') 
union all
SELECT d2.productid, d2.fieldid, d2.value
FROM tbl_fld_val d2
WHERE (d2.fieldid= 37 AND d2.value LIKE '%Farvede%')
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70091/8)

Or you can try an `OR` between your `WHERE` clauses:

```
SELECT d1.productid, d1.fieldid, d1.value
FROM tbl_fld_val d1
INNER JOIN tbl_fld_val d2 
  ON d1.productid=d2.productid
WHERE (d1.fieldid= 36 AND d1.value LIKE '%Søl%') 
  OR (d2.fieldid= 37 AND d2.value LIKE '%Farvede%');
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70091/10)

Comment: @Bluefleet, Please see a modification in the value of a row above. Now if I run following query, it does not display any records:SELECT d1.productid, d1.fieldid, d1.value
  ,d2.productid d2pid, d2.fieldid d2did, d2.value d2val
FROM tbl_fld_val d1
INNER JOIN tbl_fld_val d2 
  ON d1.productid=d2.productid
WHERE (d1.fieldid= 36 AND d1.value LIKE '%Test%') 
  AND (d2.fieldid= 37 AND d2.value LIKE '%Farvede%'); But there are columns that has fieldid as 36 and value as test.

Comment: @user1872523 what do you what the desired result to be?

Comment: Thanks @Bluefleet, you are much appreciated to save my few hours.

Answer (score 1):

whats wrong with this straightforward query :

> select productid from tbl_fld_val where (fieldid=36 and value like
>   '%Søl%') or (fieldid= 37 AND value LIKE '%Farvede%');

Comment: Don't want OR, want only those records that satisfy following rule: Condition 1 && Condition 2

Where Condition 1 = (SubCond 1_1 && SubCond 1_2)
and Condition 2 = (SubCond 2_1 && SubCond 2_2)

Answer (score 0):

try this SQL query, I used `OR` to get both `36` and `37` fieldid

```
SELECT d1.productid, d1.fieldid, d1.value
FROM tbl_fld_val d1
WHERE ( (d1.fieldid= 36 AND d1.value LIKE '%Søl%') OR (d1.fieldid= 37 AND d1.value LIKE '%Farvede%') )
```

Try: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d42ad/3

Comment: Thanks @Muthu but I want to select only matching records, that satisfy both the conditions on field id.